# Excel date values compute incorrectly

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an excel sheet where each line contains a date/time field for each 15 minute interval for the entire year.  I put "00:15:00" in A1 and "1/1/2014" in A2 and "=A2+$A$1" in A3. I then copied A3 down enough times to go thru the year.  I set column B equal to col A.  I set the format in col A to Short Date and col B to Time.  Then I converted everything to values.  When I do that, all the entries for midnight are not right.  For example the entry between Jan 1 and Jan 2, displays as 1/2/2014 and 12:00:00AM.  But the actual value is "1/1/2014  12:00:00 AM". This value is incorrect, it is 24 hours off.  What's going on here?  How can I fix it?
I'm using Office 2010.

Comment: The dates are mm/dd/yyyy.  The display shows 1/2/2014 but the formula bar shows "1/1/2014 12:00:00 AM".  Also, if I hit Edit (F2), it also shows "1/1/2014 12:00:00 AM".  If I hit Edit and then Enter, the display changes to 1/1/2014.

Comment: @pnuts - this works, apparently because the value is stored (as shown in the formula bar) as a number instead of a date.

Comment: I think the crux of the problem is that if column A has this odd combination of displaying 1/2/14 12:00:00 AM but the value is 1/1/14 12:00:00 AM and column B is set to col a and formatted as a number, the value in column B will change if I hit edit and enter on the cell in column A.  I think this is a problem with Excel, why should the value of a cell change when you hit edit and enter?

Answer (score 0):

It's standard for 12:00 AM to denote the midnight that starts the day. So, in 15-minute increments, 1/1/14 11:45 PM would typically be followed by 1/2/14 12:00 AM, followed by 1/2/14 12:15 AM.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight